# Postdata formatting

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, postdata

I have a quick question about the formatting of postData in c#. Below is what I believe to be the post data extracted from google chrome. The data is related to creating an email. If anyone has any advice or spots any errors that would be really helpful. Thanks in advance

**The Post Data**

```
/reg_json?GivenName=findmeeasy&FamilyName=notebook&AccountID=@yahoo.com&PartnerName=yahoo_default&ApiName=ValidateFields&RequestVersion=1&intl=us&u=r333.member.bf1.yahoo.com56a54898077dc5.76327249&t=omaWrw2j1XMYYqsuNAvhoksAu08PTvyAF.VLF5WV3CEDJjE1oXISM8YYtNCMH4jqCmeEiFNVFSEj9MUCaEI4XkBtmeyboO6R4H0SI2tgb1vIz0gsI_3fMFByGY9uDyBssJxV0IHFuNAH4vDMGF0aJrn9AOLwjvxvEjBnGAdd0a_O1K4EyNP6xBkP59d9htdyrvTfsWsjfxNOSEJ1Cz4I0ynjBX7jBtorMVaPeGNxPxOhkNhIeaRR1M7pwIqaN9JxS8Sz4dhVccpdLlwvct.a6PGX1fEWZnvPowfODogHPIdJ1wq3dcwa4r4uK7K.QMHdzJobys_bJwGdKBXjQx7VL6WA_0Xoe9wk3xXZ13hIaR0zaCnDvWINPyX4.40.cw59.W5So13znpBXX.B4ZiD89OByV7c_cc1gzmjPVSOOcBQVAFljk72gPqq5GNA_iWAMAgYSH0lMacvUQSOpc6XnVjshMJRqRwQncoYn7j83WmOximNzdAoOOH.C8yeF6v3uxJVhOS111OCd2N37WucRBTdMWDOSTzDCx53a7E9fCNn9p_4PUGKr07WPRj5.9svMxv.PrKg_bJdLnJI-~B&1453672621368 HTTP/1.1
```

**My Attempt at formatting**

```
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.Append("/reg_json?GivenName=findmeeasy");
postData.Append("&FamilyName=notebook");
postData.Append("&AccountID=@yahoo.com");
postData.Append("&PartnerName=yahoo_default");
postData.Append("&ApiName=ValidateFields");
postData.Append("&RequestVersion=1");
postData.Append("&intl=us");
postData.Append("&u=r333.member.bf1.yahoo.com56a54898077dc5.76327249");
postData.Append("&t=omaWrw2j1XMYYqsuNAvhoksA.....");
```

Comment: Why not just leave it as a single/simple string?

Comment: What is the question? what doesn't work? where is the error?

Comment: There was no question, I was asking for advice because I was unsure If I was on the right path.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure that both the variable name and the data value are url escaped - which they look to be. But that may be a co-incidence.

I'd do something like this

```
 using System;

 private static string MakeData(string name, string value)
 {
     return Uri.Escape(name) + "=" + Uri.Escape(value);
 }

 ...

postData.Append("/reg_json?" + MakeData("GivenName", "findmeeasy"));
postData.Append("&" + MakeData("FamilyName", "notebook"));
/// etc.
```